# how to add concatenate multiple NSString in one String in iphone

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsstring

I have 5 String i want that  they must be store in singe NSString all the values separate with `|` sign

```
   NSString *first=@"Ali";
   NSString *second=@"Imran";
   NSString *third=@"AliImran";
   NSString *fourth=@"ImranAli";
   NSString *fifth=@"Ali Imran Jamshed";
```

I want to all these in single NSString to store and all values separated by given sign.

Comment: by making a new string containing all these values and separating them by a separator string, you will need always to parse it, split, merge, bla bla. use an NSDictionary and you will get and set them by keys.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
NSArray *myStrings = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:first, second, third, fourth, fifth, nil];
NSString *joinedString = [myStrings componentsJoinedByString:@"|"];
// release myStrings if not using ARC.
```

Comment: If you mean it's nil, then no, because it's a nil terminated list. If any of the values is nil, all the other values after that will be ignored. If you mean it's an empty string, then yes, it will show an empty string (nothing) between two separators.

Answer (score 30):

```
you can try ....
NSString *joinString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@|%@|%@|%@|%@",youstring1,youstring2,youstring3,youstring4,youstring5];
```

Answer (score 11):

**Short solution:**

```
NSString *str = [@[nstring1, nstring2, nstring3] componentsJoinedByString:@","];
```

Answer (score 4):

I guess what DrummerB suggested, is the best way. You have to store the strings in data structure. Array or dictionary for that matter.
If you just want to use strings it is not impossible, but it will be unwise. Here you go :

```
NSString*first=@"Ali";  
first = [first stringByAppendingString:@"|"];
first = [first stringByAppendingString:@"Imran"];
first = [first stringByAppendingString:@"|"];
first = [first stringByAppendingString:@"AliImran"];
first = [first stringByAppendingString:@"|"];
first = [first stringByAppendingString:@"ImranAli"];
first = [first stringByAppendingString:@"|"];
first = [first stringByAppendingString:@"Ali Imran Jamshed"];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *stringsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:first, second, third, fourth, fifth, nil];
NSString *combinedString = [stringsArray componentsJoinedByString:@","];
```

The combined String looks like this `@"Ali,Imran,AliImran,ImranAli,Ali Imran Jamshed"`;

Comment: it is not shwoing any thing in NSLOg when print

Answer (score 1):

To improve on Nitish's answer, you can reduce the number of lines by following this:

```
NSString *first=@"Ali";  
first = [first stringByAppendingString:[@"|" stringByAppendingString:[@"Imran" stringByAppendingString:@"|"]]];
.
```