# Problems with componentsJoinedByString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablestring

I want to create a **NSString** with componentsJoinedByString, and then add a NSMutableString. How can I do that?

I know that I can't change a NSString when I've created it. I tried this:

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat: [this.array componentsJoinedByString:@ " , "], someMutableString];
```

But that doesn't add the mutable string.

Hank

Answer (score 1):

Think simple!

```
[this.array componentsJoinedByString:@" , "]
```

returns you a string. Now you can append two strings to form a new one with `stringByAppendingString:`, so just do:

```
[[this.array componentsJoinedByString:@" , "] stringByAppendingString:someMutableString];
```

[*As others have pointed out, you approach was wrong as you sued `stringWithFormat:` but didn't supply any literal format - so the results of joining your strings, as the first argument, was used as the format. You normally would see a compiler warning that you have a non-literal format*]

Answer (score 0):

You forgot [Format Specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1). Do it this way,

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [this.array componentsJoinedByString:@ " , "], someMutableString];
```

See [String Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html) also.

Answer (score 0):

You missing some basic string manipulation

```
NSString *stringCombined = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [this.array componentsJoinedByString:@ " , "], someMutableString];
```

this link is another approach

[how to add concatenate multiple NSString in one String in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12156780/how-to-add-concatenate-multiple-nsstring-in-one-string-in-iphone)